# Mixed models with missing fixed level on some clusters

Tags: mixed-model, categorical-data, multilevel-analysis, missing-data, predictor

There are a lot of publications on missing data and unbalances in mixed models but I missed the issue when unbalances or missings relates to levels of a categorical variables.
Let's assume we want to study an education concept `treat`in schools. For this kind of analysis a mixed model would be appropriate. In R-notation this would be:

```r
score ~ treat + sex + age + 1|school
```

Let's say that the number of schools are 50. If each school has females and males and similar age distribution I wouldn't have any concern to use a mixed model. Is this model still suitable if

1. 30 schools have females/males and 10 schools have only female and 10 only males?
2. 25 schools have only females and 25 only males?
3. age distribution are different since 5 schools have only higher classes and 45 lower classes?

How is the appropriate naming of this kind of unbalance or missing?

Comment: This might help: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/unpublished/Bafumi_Gelman_Midwest06.pdf

Comment: Unbalanced data doesn't change in a direct way whether a model is suitable. It is more like influencing performance and accuracy of tests. Or a problem in the interpretation of coefficients may occur when you have a misspecified model.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for why this gender distribution exists across schools?

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand This is only a hypothetical example. Reason could be: privat school policy.

Comment: Using hypothetical examples makes it harder to get an on point answer. In your schools example, it's seems reasonable to assume that there are three categories of schools: "only grils", "only boys" and "co-ed" and that they are not exchangeable. (The schools would have different policies, parents would prefer one category of school over the other for reasons...) In short, the random effect `1|school` may be hard to justify. In this hypothetical example.

Comment: Aside from Dipetkov's comments, which I believe are correct (but not specifically about statistics), whether or not a certain model is correct or not is often not a statistical question. You can use statistics to quantify by how much a certain model is correct or not and whether one seems better than another, but the modelling itself is not a 'statistics' question. Modelling and statistics become integrated because we need to figure out  approximate models that work well in a statistical sense (*usefulness* of models is a statistical concept) or because we express some statistical model.

Comment: @dipetkov. Thanks for the comment. I think I got the idea. In case of this hypothetical example the model could be misspecified since the the reason for this caterogical unbalance is not random. If the random variable would be classes and there are a lot of classes with small numbers of student the probability of only one sex classes is high. So, if the categorical unbalance is randomly a mixed model should be adequate for data with categorical unbalance.

Comment: @Sextus Empiricus. See my comment to dipetkov.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that it may not be helpful to assume that there is one statistical approach to fit all problems (as long as one or two conditions apply). It's better to start with the actual problem, not with an abstraction/generalization. It matters what Y is, what Xs you have, what are the units of analysis and how they were collected, how they are grouped into groups/classes, etc....